# How to define compile time constants based on platform (Linux vs Windows) in C# / .Net.Core?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, csproj, conditional-compilation

Inspired by this [blog](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/11/05/platform-conditional-compilation-in-net-core/), I tried to implement this like so:

```
<DefineConstants Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">Windows</DefineConstants>
<DefineConstants Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">POSIX</DefineConstants>
```

but I get this error:

`The function "IsOSPlatform" on type "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" is not available for execution as an MSBuild property function`

Is there a way to get around this problem? The project loads perfectly without those two `DefineConstants` lines.

[image: MSBuild Error]

Comment: Why are you NOT just using the <PropertyGroup> setup as actually suggested by the blog?

Comment: I tired it, it gives me the same error. The issue is that `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` is not available

Comment: It looks like you are building with an older version of MSBuild. Which environment are you using? The current msbuild and tools version is 16

Comment: I'm using `mono`. Maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: Which version of mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method only works on the 15.0 (or up) version of MSBuild. Since mono right now does not come with this version of MSBuild.

There is an open issue on this [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/17010)

Visual studio can compile the code with this in the `.csproj` file.